# Appending Blurry Images to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension with a GUI added to the DOM using methods such as
document.createElement('div') followed by document.body.appendChild() function. I am then creating new components and appending them to my previously created elements.

So far everything is working fine and I am constructing my GUI well except for images. For example, I am writing something like:

`guiImg = document.createElement('img')`

`guiDiv.appendChild(guiImg)`

`guiImg.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('images/imgName')`

However, when all my images load insanely blurry and unviewable. I am using manifest v3 and have added all my images to web_accessible_resources in my manifest.json. All my images are png files. I have tried to debug and there doesn't seem to be much help online. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do these images also look blurry in the dev tools network tab?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Just checked and no they do not. they look perfectly fine